# Scrapy request doesn't yield full HTML - but Requests library does

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I am building a crawl.spider to scrape statutory law data from the following website (https://www.azleg.gov/viewdocument/?docName=https://www.azleg.gov/ars/1/00101.htm). I am aiming to extract the statute text, which is contained in the following XPath [//div[@class = 'first']/p/text()]. This path should provide the statute text.

All of my scrapy requests are yielding incomplete html responses, such that when I search for the relevant xpath queries, it yields an empty list. However, when I use the requests library, the html downloads correctly.

Using XPath tester online, I've verified that my xpath queries should produce the desired content. Using scrapy shell, I've viewed the response object from scrapy in my browser - and it looks just like it does when I'm browsing natively. I've tried enabling middleware for both BeautifulSoup and Selenium, but neither has appeared to work.

Here's my crawl spider

```py
class AZspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "arizona"
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.azleg.gov/viewdocument/?docName=https://www.azleg.gov/ars/1/00101.htm",
    ]

    rule = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class = 'article']"), callback="parse_stats_az", follow=True),)
    def parse_stats_az(self, response):
        statutes = response.xpath("//div[@class = 'first']/p")
        yield{
        "statutes":statutes
        }
```

And here's the code that succsessfuly generated the correct response object

```py
az_leg = requests.get("https://www.azleg.gov/viewdocument/?docName=https://www.azleg.gov/ars/1/00101.htm")
```

Comment: If I remove `Rule` from `scrapy` spider and simply print the HTML content of the response, then I am getting the whole content. You have to be more descriptive in explaining what should be the output and what output you are getting with `scrapy` and what is not.

Comment: @TonyMontana - thank you - I've edited the post for clarity. To summarize, my xpath queries in scrapy are unexpectedly returning empty lists. In requests, they are not.

Comment: May I know why you are using `Rule`and `LinkExtractor` here in scrapy? Because while using `requests`, you are not using anything

Comment: @TonyMontana the ultimate goal is pagination, so I wanted to use a crawl spider, class, and rules. To test that the html could even be downloaded correctly on a single page, I used requests.

Comment: Buddy, go step by step. Why are you worrying about the pagination if you are not getting correct HTML code at first? As I told, remove everything and write a simple `scrapy` spider which will parse the above mentioned URL which you have used with `requests`. And then check whether you are getting correct HTML or not. Your are trying to find `statute` text at first, then try to find that first only, then worry about pagination.

Comment: @TonyMontana As demonstrated in the scrappy shell, the problem persists with single requests. Fetching the url and attempting to parse by the above xpath ("//div[@class = 'first']/p") yields an empty list. That doesn't seem to depend on the pagination.

Comment: Ok, I got the problem. You are trying to fetch `div` containing data of **Designation and citation**. Please correct me if I am wrong. But this whole `div` is being generated from the sub-URL of the main URL, which is "https://www.azleg.gov/ars/1/00101.htm". This URL is passed in the main URL as a `docName` parameter. So, if you want to use the above-mentioned XPath query and fetch content inside it, then my advice will be to use this sub-URL and not the main URL. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @TonyMontana that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: no problem. But still, I am confused about how it is not working in scrapy shell. If you use the main URL in scrapy shell and then enter command `view(response)`, it will open HTML content of the URL in the browser and in that you'll find all content inside it. I think it is generating the HTML using javascript on the fly, hence you don't get the desired output in scrapy shell. I don't know whether this is the exact reason of it, but I would love if someone with expertise with scrapy explains this behavior as it is working fine with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` library.